# Is it possible to use std::generate on an empty std::vector for which we have only called .reserve?

Tags: c++, std

My main function:

```cpp
#include <vector>
//#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    std::vector<char> v;
    int len = 2 * 5 + 1;
    v.reserve(len);

    // using for loop and push_back

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        (i % 2) ? v.push_back(' ') : v.push_back('|');

    // using generate

    // std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [n = 0]() mutable { return (n++ % 2) ? ' ' : '|'; });
    // std::generate_n(v.begin(), len, [n = 0]() mutable { return (n++ % 2) ? ' ' : '|'; });

    for (const char& c : v)
        std::cout << c;

    return 0;
}
```

Using for loop and push_back I get the output:

| | | | | |

Using std::generate has no effect, and using std::generate_n results in a failed assertion:

Expression: cannot seek vector iterator after end

As I understand it, calling .reserve doesn't change the "distance" between iterators begin and end, so I can't pass them to std::generate in order to place ' ' and '|' in the memory I reserved for v. I would have to increase v.end by len (len+1?), is that even possible? Or is there another way to make this work, without using .push_back or similar operations, or without initializing reserved memory with something then overwriting it? Also not sure if the lambda is correct, but that's not important.

Comment: "I would have to increase v.end by len (len+1?), is that even possible? " you are looking for `resize` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize.

Comment: `std::generate_t(std::back_inserter(v),`. But it's not necessarily faster than resize + what you have now.

Comment: is there some particular reason why you want only reserve? "or without initializing reserved memory with something then overwriting it?"  why? I mean there can be reasons but for a vector of `char` it doesnt hurt to use the most simple and just start with a vector of proper size

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai This is a simpler example where I create this vector of chars with 2 * 5 + 1 elements, eventually I want to create vectors with 2 * dim + 1 elements, so I don't want to initialize memory with something, then overwrite for no reason. Also I'm trying to replace for loops with std algorithms, so that's why I'm trying to make generate work instead of for loop and push_back.

Comment: please do not add the answer to your question. If you like you can post an answer below in the asnwer section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::generate_n` with a `std::back_inserter` on the container.

This will resize the container as it generates.

The reserve is optional, but it will save on container resizes and reallocations possibly.

Comment: additionally, you can use resize() and the begin() iterator.

Comment: @Raildex OP does not want to initialize the data then overwrite it, so no they cannot.